# python socket.recv hangs, however I see the frame in tcpdump

Tags: python, sockets, rhel

I have below code to send command, but python script never exits. it hangs.
i am using RHEL 6.4 x86_64. scapy srp1 also hangs.

```
from socket import *
from scapy.all import *
from myproto import *

def sendeth(REQUEST, interface = "eth0"):
    """Send raw Ethernet packet on interface."""
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW)
    s.bind((interface, 0))
    s.send(REQUEST)
    data = s.recv(2048)
    hexdump(data)


p = Ether()/MYPROTO()/MYPROTO1()
hexdump(p)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "Sent %d-byte Ethernet packet on eth3" % sendeth(str(p), 'eth3')
```

But after execution, I see the frame on tcpdump, but the python code never exits and need a control^C.

```
tcpdump: WARNING: eth3: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
17:10:37.122445 00:00:00:00:00:00 (oui Ethernet) > Broadcast, ethertype  Unknown (0x8096), length 34:
    0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0000 0000 0000 8096 0001
    0x0010:  0001 1500 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ffff
    0x0020:  eafe
17:10:37.133248 00:04:25:1c:a0:02 (oui Unknown) > Broadcast, ethertype Unknown (0x8096), length 76:
    0x0000:  ffff ffff ffff 0004 251c a002 8096 0001
    0x0010:  0001 9500 0028 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0020:  0000 f1f0 f100 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000
    0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0803 0087 1634 8096 8096
    0x0040:  e4f2 0000 0f21 fffc 5427 ffff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>By the time you call `recv()` on the socket, the network stack in the kernel already dispatched the frame you are sending, and noticing that nothing is waiting for it on the local host, discarded it.</del>

<del>Try running sender and receiver as different processes.</del>

#### Edit 0:

Try adding your specific protocol number as the third parameter to `socket()`. Here is an example that grabs ten ethernet frames off my `eth0` on Debian (needs `root` privileges):

```
import socket
# from linux/if_etheer.h, all ethernet protocols, be very careful
ETH_P_ALL=0x0003
s=socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.htons(ETH_P_ALL))
s.bind(('eth0', 0)) 
for n in range(10):
    print n, len(s.recv(2048))
```

Comment: Hmm... no.  The kernel buffers data destined for an open socket.

Comment: With the normal transport  protocols like TCP and UDP - yes. With raw sockets - I am not so sure.

Comment: Hmm, now that I think about it — neither am I.  Unfortunately I'm unable to revert my downvote any longer.

Comment: I tried different process  to recv, yet I do not see the frame at python. I am not sure if this has to do anything with some secret socket flags which I am missing or some system issue of stack not fwd to python. I have "libpcap-1.0.0-6.20091201git117cb5.el6.x86_64" on my system.

Comment: Yes, I tried the same today and was about to post the same today. anyways specific ether type solved the issue and that too in single process.

Answer (score 1):

strace helped to find the solution as it was waiting on select -
solution is -

```
from socket import *
from scapy.all import *
from myproto import *
MYPROTOTYPE = 0x8096

p = Ether()/MYPROTO()/MYPROTO1()
hexdump(p)

from socket import socket, PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW

s = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, MYPROTOTYPE)
s.bind(("eth3", MYPROTOTYPE))
s.send(str(p))
data = s.recv(2048)
hexdump(data)
```